# Gap on the right of the screen on mobile view

Tags: html, css, width

I am building one website and I have a weird gap on the right size of the screen. [image]

This gap appears only at mobile view and with portrait view (with landscape everything seems to be OK). Width of body and html is set to 100% with margin and padding set to 0. I figured out that the real width of the body should be 105vw, but is this true for all devices?

Any way how to clearly solve it?

Site: http://valkovic.eu:8080/JanWilliamDrnek/

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. We do not want links to sites that will change - especially if you fix the issue

Comment: Reference site is not loading :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the first time but not the second maybe you are adjusting as I looked.

it seemed that the logo  was pushing out over the body

.title img { margin: 2em auto;} in the css fixed the issue for me.

Unsure about the 105vw unless you are trying to hide something offscreen the max value should be 100vw.

Comment: Thank you, image margin was the issue. Althought I dont know, why width of the image influence the width of the page, but nevermind :D.

Comment: You can stop the parent element / body from expanding with the css property [overflow: hidden;] on a parent element that you don't want to expand. With this property now if the inner element is too big for it's container the overflowing parts will be hidden. :)